# Como percorrer um dict e passar os valores APP_KEY e APP_SECRET no post

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

Estou tentando passar os valores de um dicionário onde está armazenado 31 `APP_KEY` e `APP_SECRET`, gostaria de percorrer e atribuir os valores a cada passa do meu `for` porém não estou conseguindo.

```
empresas ={
            'key_facilities':"...",'secret_facilities':"...",
            'key_boss':"...",'secret_boss':"...",
            'key_hub':"...",'secret_hub':"..."
            }

for chave in empresas.keys():

    # Vaidando o retorno
    c = empresas[chave]
    print(c)

    data3 = {
                'app_key': c,
                'app_secret': c,
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                "call": 'ListarMovimentos',
                "param": [{'nPagina': 5, 'nRegPorPagina':10}]
            }

    # Efetuando o get
    resp= requests.post(
            'https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/mf/', json=data3)
                    
    resp = resp.json()
```

Answer (score -3):

```py
import requests

app_key = None
app_secret = None

empresas = {
            'key_facilities':"...",'secret_facilities':"...",
            'key_boss':"...",'secret_boss':"...",
            'key_hub':"...",'secret_hub':"..."
}

for chave in empresas.keys():
    if "key" in chave:
        app_key = empresas[chave]
    elif "secret" in chave:
        app_secret = empresas[chave]

    data3 = {
                'app_key': app_key,
                'app_secret': app_secret,
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                "call": 'ListarMovimentos',
                "param": [{'nPagina': 5, 'nRegPorPagina':10}]
            }

    resp = requests.post('https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/mf/', json=data3)
    resp = resp.json()
    print(resp)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: Olá, tudo bem? 
Segui sua orientação porém  o ('app_secret': app_secret) não está localizando o valor do app_secret  dentro do elif.


                                                                                                                                                   
 "secret": secret_app
              ^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'secret_app' where it is not associated with a value

Comment: Eu editei o comentário, veja se funciona agora.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.